# Why is my index not found by tomcat?

Tags: grails, tomcat6

I have been developing a grails application for a few years now and recently have run into a curious problem with my deployment of the application to tomcat6. I can access the log-in page.  I can log-in and get authenticated.  However, when being rediected to my index page I get a 404 /myapp/ resource not available.

The interesting piece is that I can navigate to other pages in the application and perform any action that I need to, but when navigating back to the home page it returns a 404 not found.

I searched the deployed view directories and the index.gsp is present where it is supposed to be.  my spock tests haven't failed.  I'm at a loss.  I've not modified my home controller or the index page itself in over two years.  What am I missing?

I'm using grails 2.1.1 and tomcat6

**UPDATE:**

Here is my UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller: "home",action:"index")
        //(view: "/index")

    // special mapping for jqgrid errors
    "500"(controller: "errors", action: "validation", exception: ValidationException)

    //"500"(controller: "errors")
    "500"(view: '/error')
    //"/searchable"(view:"/searchable/index")
    /*name homeView: "/bullMaster" {
        controller = "bullMaster"
        action = "index"
    }
   */
}
```

}

and my HomeController is real basic:

```
class HomeController {

def index =  {

    render(view:"index")
}

def termsAndConditions ={
    render(view:"termsAndConditions")
}
```

}

I typically navigate to the application with:

```
http://ipAddress:8080/appName/
```

Comment: a wild shot, but is it possible, that you have deleted something in `Urlmappings.groovy`?

Comment: are you accessing your page through a reverse proxy? try to access the page directly (8080 or 8443) in order to double check, that your main page is not just failing to render. i guess that either the page is throwing an error or your reverse proxy has issues.

Comment: I added my UrlMappings and Home Controller just for additional reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any errors in logs?

Try next, one by another (test after every step):

1. `"/"(controller: "home")` - remove 'action'.
2. Change `def index = {}` to `def index() {}`
3. Add 'layout': `render(view:"index", layout:null)`
4. Remove almost all code from 'index.gsp'.
5. Add /home to render: `render(view:"/home/index")`
6. Replace `render(view:"index")` to `render text: 'test'`
7. Is this url works? http://yourip:8080/appName/home/index

It may help to find an issue. Will you always get an error 404 after every step?